# How to enter an NSArray of integers from console in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, user-input

I am trying to do solve some basic algorithm and Data structure problem using Objective-c and i found it little hard.
I need to enter an array of integers from console, what's the best way to do this?

Please help direct me to any link or documentation.

Thanks,

Comment: Wait, what?  You mean you want to create an array from LLDB and somehow have it affect program execution?

Comment: What "console" are you talking about?

Comment: Probably a "Command Line Tool" on OS X that reads from standard input.

Comment: i want to input this from debugger console.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:** The plan is the following:

1. Read from the console and save the input as a c-string.
2. Convert this c-String to an NSString on which we can call the method `componentsSeparatedByString:`.
3. This method returns an NSArray of NSStrings of single numbers.
4. After that we loop through the NSArray, create an NSNumber with the string's content for each string and store that NSNumber in an NSMutableArray.
5. We NSLog() the NSArray or you can do whatever you want with it's components.

So here is the fun:

```
NSMutableArray *numbersAsNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
char input[1000] = {};
scanf("%s", input);
NSString *inputString = [NSString stringWithCString:input encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *numbersAsStringsArray = [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (NSString *aNumberAsString in numbersAsStringsArray) {
    NSNumber *aNumber = @([aNumberAsString integerValue]);
    [numbersAsNumbersArray addObject:aNumber];
}
NSLog(@"%@", numbersAsNumbersArray);
```

*Input:* `3,5,6,7`

*Output:* `(3,5,6,7)`

Note: The braces indicate that the numbers inside are stored in an NSArray

Last but not least something to read ;)

[NSArray Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) and its mutable subclass [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSString Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html), especially the [method we use](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-componentsSeparatedByString_)

**Edit 2:** As mentioned in the comments by [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) (Thank you!) here is the short version of the code above:

```
NSMutableArray *numbersAsNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
char input[1000] = {};
scanf("%s", input);
NSArray *numbersAsStringsArray = [[NSString stringWithCString:input encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
numbersAsNumbersArray = [numbersAsStringsArray valueForKey:@"integerValue"];
NSLog(@"%@", numbersAsNumbersArray);
```

Comment: You can reduce the loop to `numbersAsNumbersArray = [numbersAsStringsArray valueForKey:@"integerValue"]` :-)

Comment: You are absolutely right :) You can even save 6 more characters using `[numbersAsNumbersArray addObject:@([aNumberAsString integerValue])]` ;) I just wanted to make it a bit more detailed. I'll add a short version shortly which I like much more.

Comment: What I meant is that you can apply `valueForKey:@"integerValue"` to the *array* `numbersAsStringsArray`, replacing the entire loop. - But it was just a remark/suggestion.